# Algorithm for randomly generating polyhedrons?

Tags: algorithm, graphics, computational-geometry, polyhedra

I want to randomly generate polyhedrons which need not be convex. What is the most efficient way for doing so?

I can think of an algorithm for generating random convex polyhedrons, but am unable to figure out a way for generating non-convex ones. How to generate a general polyhedron?

Taking it a step further, generalising my question to an n dimension space, how to randomly generate bounded finite polytopes?

Comment: Search [OEIS](https://oeis.org/) for [Polyhedron](https://oeis.org/search?q=Polyhedron&sort=&language=&go=Search). Articles sometimes give algorithms. If not then if you find a sequence you at least have a bound and something to work from and test against.

Comment: @GuyCoder: what is the connection with the question ??

Comment: You can generate random convex polyhedrons and unite them. Look for a ready-made union algorithm. If you also want holes, combine with subtraction.

Comment: It depends on data structure, representing a polyhedron. So, your first step should be to choose the data structure

Comment: Not my cup of tea but: Why not create convex polyhedron first and then create a concave features in it by shifting some or group of vertexes inside it (towards center) ? another option is to generate several convex polyhedrons and join/union them together at random locations and orientations....

Comment: @HEKTO : The data structure I am going use is the same as in wavefront .OBJ file format.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Thanks for your suggestion. I feel that there are two issues. The first is, if the two convex polyhedra dont intersect each other then their union is not a  connected polyhedra, but rather two connected components, which is not preferrable. In that case we can discard the sample. The second issue is does this random generation algorithm have a uniform distribution over all the polyhedrons. Because during random generation a uniform sampling is always preferred.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: I had a small doubt. If I take a convex polyhedron, lets say a cube and remove a small cube from the inside, Is the resulting object still a polyhedron?

Comment: @Aalok_G: yes it is.

Comment: "a uniform distribution over all the polyhedrons": you must give a statistical meaning to that statement. Good luck ! Are you even able to sample "a uniform distribution" of convex polyhedra (whatever that means)?